# Is overloading systematically for r-value references a good pattern?

Tags: c++11, overloading, rvalue-reference

I have a class that behaves very similar to (the C++11 version of) `std::ostream`, to which I can stream many different (unrelated) types.

`class mystream{...some implementation...};`

The typical function to define is

`mystream& operator<<(mystream& ms, type1 const& t1){...}`

`mystream& operator<<(mystream& ms, type2 const& t2){...}`

etc.

However, (just like with C++11's stream) I would like to stream-on-construction. For example:

`mystream{} << t1;`

To be able to do this, I overload on l-value references, for each type:

```
mystream& operator<<(mystream&& ms, type1 const& t1){
   return ms << t1; // this calls the l-value version
}
```

*The code is not complicated, but it is repetitive because I have to do it for all types involved.* Because of the nature of this class it makes sense to use on references and l-value references.

**The question is if this is the correct approach? Should I write two functions for each type? Is this a good pattern?**

Secondary question: Of course I could do some some template magic to accept l-value references when appropriate but again I don't know if this is the recommended path.

Ternary question: Should the function return `mystream&` (like above) or `mystream&&`.

---

This is the example code:

```
class A{};
class B{};

class mystream{};

mystream& operator<<(mystream& ms, A const& a){return ms;} // (1)
mystream& operator<<(mystream& ms, B const& b){return ms;} // (2)

mystream& operator<<(mystream&& ms, A const& a){return ms; /*ms << a;*/} // (3)
mystream& operator<<(mystream&& ms, B const& b){return ms; /*ms << a;*/} // (4)

int main(){

    mystream ms;
    ms << A{};
    ms << B{};

    mystream{} << A{}; // ok only if line (3) is defined
    mystream{} << B{}; // ok only if line (4) is defined

}
```

If I comment line (3) the error message is

```
fatal error: invalid operands to binary expression ('mystream' and 'A')
        mystream{} << A{}; // ok only if line (3) is defined
        ~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~
././random.hpp:146:11: note: candidate function not viable: expects an l-value for 1st argument
mystream& operator<<(mystream& ms, A const& a){return ms;} // (1)
```

If I comment line (1) the converse happens

```
fatal error: invalid operands to binary expression ('mystream' and 'A')
        ms << A{};
        ~~ ^  ~~~
././random.hpp:149:11: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'mystream' to 'mystream &&' for 1st argument
mystream& operator<<(mystream&& ms, A const& a){return ms; /*ms << a;*/} // (3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ defines a single function template that takes an ostream rvalue reference:

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, class T >
basic_ostream< CharT, Traits >& operator<<( basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&& os, 
                                            const T& value );
```

It calls an appropriate insertion operator. Accordingly, you should only define

```
template <typename X>
mystream& operator<< (mystream&& ms, const X& x)
{
    ms << x;
    return ms;
}
```

Comment: Is that also true for concrete `std::o?stream` classes? (like `std::ofstream`). Anyway, I think `    ms << x;` in your code will call the l-value reference for the concrete class. Also, doing that will not work for me because this call will not work. `mystream ms{}; ms << t1;`.

Comment: It always returns the base class reference. If you are getting compilation errors please show the full code and the full error messages.

Comment: Yes, but relies on having an l-value version of the function in the derived concrete class. My question doesn't involve inheritance or base classes. I added the example code to show why apparently it is needed to have the two versions.

Comment: @alfC I don't understand your problem. You replace all `&&` versions of the functions with a single template like I shown. The `&` versions stay intact. Do you still have compilation errors?

Comment: Ok, sorry I missed the second part of your answer. This answers my question. Would you return the type `mystream&` or `mystream&&` (with forward). 2) I tried to use sfinae to have better compiler error but I wasn't able (with gcc at least I get recursion error) `template<class T> auto operator<<(mystream&& ms, T const& t)->decltype(ms << t){...}`

Comment: 1) `mystream&` just like `ostream&`.